# Página perfil não se encaixa em telas de 15" (laptops) quando usada no navegador Opera

Tags: bug, layout

Em monitores/telas com 15 polegadas, o layout do perfil não cabe, por exemplo:

[image: profile]

Esse **"bug"** ocorre nas páginas `pt.stackoverflow.com/users/<id>` e `meta.stackexchange.com/users/<id>`.

Em outras páginas, o "novo menu" (menu à esquerda) do Opera **não afeta o layout principal do site**.

resolução: 1280x800

> **LEIA:** Estou ciente de que isso se deve ao menu do Opera e entendo que talvez seja algo que nunca será resolvido, mas estou relatando que alguém percebe o mesmo problema e não entende por que está ocorrendo.

---

> Cross-post: [Profile page don't fit 15-inch displays (laptops) when used in Opera browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313927/198279)

Comment: Não é só no Opera. Aparentemente a página de perfil não está responsiva, como outras páginas também. Estou no Google Chrome e ao redimensionar a barra horizontal aparece, isso apenas na área do Perfil, Tour e no Sobre Nós (onde testei). Acho que ainda estão adaptando. A maioria das páginas já estão responsivas.